# Cannot ban with ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I cannot ban a GuildMember using its ID, only with a mention. There are no errors in the console.

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
    return message.channel.send("Invalid Permissions");
}

let User = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

if (!User) {
    return message.channel.send("Invalid User");
}

if (User.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
    return message.reply("Can't ban that one, he also can ban");
}

let banReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);

if (!banReason) {
    banReason = "None";
}

console.log(`USER = ${User}`);

User.ban({ reason: banReason });

var UserID = User.id;
console.log(`USER ID = ${UserID}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `cache`, introduced in discord.js V12 - please look [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)

```js
let userPending = message.guild.members.cache.fetch(message.mentions.members.first().id) || message.guild.members.cache.fetch(args[0]);

let user = await userPending;
```

This will ensure the bot searches for the correct `guildMember`

Comment: Why fetch all? Just fetch the one user mentioned...

Comment: Also it's not `member(...)` it's `members.cache.get(message.mentions.members.first().id)`

Comment: ahh, rookie error, thank you @LoganDevine

Comment: Also, you need to await fetch instead of just getting it (it can be uncached). I made a suggested edit to your post, so now we wait for the queue.

Comment: i'm really not having a good coding day today, thank you

Comment: Hey, I just been messing with edits you guys made and I am getting an error of: (node:6812) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: members is not defined

Comment: I added what @LoganDevine said. and the code is now: https://srcb.in/gf4iC6c2px

Comment: Well yes, you need to use `message.guild.members` because you did not make a variable `members` in your code.